# Can't understand the way the number of items is computed in a recursive knapsack function

Tags: c, recursion, knapsack-problem

I understand recursion on a basic level (I have been studying different exercises about it) but I can't grasp how it works in that case in particular.
Specifically, I can't understand when and how the n-th element of the array is considered. To me, this function starts computing elements from n-1, but it's clear it actually does not when checking the results. Why is that?

```
int knapsack(Item items[], int n, int knapsize){ 
  if((knapsize <= 0) || (n == 0)) return 0; 
  if(items[n-1].weight > knapsize) return knapsack(items, n-1, knapsize); 
  return max(knapsack(items, n-1, knapsize - items[n-1].weight) + items[n-1].value, knapsack(items, n-1, knapsize));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `items[n-1].weight` accesses and considers the `n`-th item. (Remember that arrays are indexed starting from zero in C.) Can you clarify what is unclear?

Comment: Why does it access the n-th item? Shouldn't it access the n-1th one...? I've got the impression I'm stumbling on something silly

Comment: Arrays are indexed starting from `0`. So an array of size `3` has elements at index `0`, `1` and `2`, but not `3`.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes that was very silly hahaha.

Comment: The `return` statement potentially calls `knapsack` (with all recursions!) _three_ times!